# "Updataredirect" being prefixed to URLs in Edge and Brave

Tags: browser, internet

When I am attempting to reach some, but not all, websites, something along the line is adding

```
http://192.168.8.1/html/quicksetup.html?randid=3103461595?updataredirect=
```

to the front of the URL. This results in a page like this appearing:-

[image: 404 page]

It does this using Brave or Edge on Windows 10. Not for all websites, but for those it does it to, it always does it to. Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: Looks like a broken captive portal to me. The router is trying to redirect you to a sign-in or setup page before it lets you use the internet. Can you navigate to http://192.168.8.1 ?

Comment: @SamForbis, yes I can navigate to that IP Address. It appears to be "DrayTek Vigor" login. I've never heard of it.

Comment: That's your router's login page. Something's likely wrong with the config on that router. If you don't own the router, you may need to contact your building manager or ISP to get them to fix it. Does this happen on other devices as well?

Comment: The router is a mobile WIFI on the dinner table, new today. I'll see if I can connect my phone to it.

Comment: The login should be username admin password admin if it's still set to the default. See if you can go to that DrayTek login page and use those credentials.

Comment: @SamForbis, using the phone has similar results; the websites I can't connect to using the computer fail on the phone (although that reports a data connectivity error, whatever that is). But I might be mistaken - the phone could be doing its own thing.

Comment: @SamForbis no I can't. The phone also displayed a login dialogue but failing that didn't appear to make any difference.

Comment: If the router is yours, try a factory reset. If it belongs to the ISP, contact their Support.

Comment: I know this is an old question but did you solve this? And the websites you get redirected on - are they HTTP instead of HTTPS? I am having a similar issue (https://superuser.com/questions/1691438/modem-redirecting-http-sites-to-itself-192-168-1-1)

Comment: @Muon, can't help very much there. Since then I've had a new Internet provider, a new router and a new computer. Don't have this trouble any more, but that probably isn't a practical solution for you.

Comment: Thanks for responding @Brian. Glad it's not an issue for you anymore. I'll keep experimenting in the meantime.