# Modem redirecting HTTP sites to itself (192.168.1.1)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, modem

I have a Huawei E8372h-608 WiFi modem. I'm having a strange problem where whenever I try to access a site via HTTP I am redirected to the modem at 192.168.1.1. I can load sites via HTTPS just fine but there are some sites I use frequently that don't support this.

I have tested this on multiple browsers and devices and still get the same issue. I think it might be some kind of security feature but I have no idea how to turn it off (I have combed through the modem settings).

I've tried some workarounds including changing DNS servers and also installing the [https-everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere) browser plugin but nothing has worked for me. Any solutions or ideas would be appreciated. Thanks!

---

**Edit**
Here is an example of redirected URL that I get when trying to visit: http://www.bom.gov.au/australia/meteye/

http://192.168.1.1/html/redirect.html?randid=145540123?updataredirect=www.bom.gov.au/australia/meteye/

Comment: Is this happening only on WIFI?  Do you have anything like a "captive portal" enabled on the router?

Comment: Hi Dave. Yes, only on WiFi. And there's no captive portal or similar features enabled.

Comment: When I google that device I am seeing a 4G dongle.  Are you using 4G to connect?      If so, does the problem persist if you take the SIM card and use it from a phone?  Who is your carrier?  Does this device allow other computers to connect through it?  If so, is the problem apparent for all devices?

Comment: Shot in the dark, but have you tried an older browser (Firefox/Chrome prior to 91)?

Comment: Thanks @Dave. Yes, it is a 4G dongle. I get the same issue when connecting to the modem WiFi from my phone. But the issue is not present when I use the sim card from a mobile phone and connect to the network directly. So I am confident that the issue is being caused by the modem.

Comment: Hi @Anaksunaman. I have tried using Chrome (96.0.4664.55), Chrome Android (96.0.4664.45) Safari (14.1.1), Firefox (72.0.2) and Firefox Developer Edition (92.0b9). The problem persists across them all.

Comment: @davidgo, I have edited the question to show an example of the redirected URL.

Comment: @anaksuaman I dont think this is a browser issue.

Comment: Here's a similar question that remains unanswered. The redirect URL is very similar. 
https://superuser.com/questions/1532523/updataredirect-being-prefixed-to-urls-in-edge-and-brave

Comment: Bit of a long shot, but I wonder if the APN setting is wrong.  Find the correct APN setting with your mobile provider and make sure its reflected in your modem settings (https://liveu.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360053709513-Logging-Into-Your-Huawei-Wingle-E8372-and-Configuring-APN-and-Subnet)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @davidgo. Good thought. The APN settings actually were incorrect so I updated them to match my service provider. Unfortunately, the problem still persists even after rebooting the device.